# Будут ли обновленные методы Android API 31 работать на более низком уровне API?

Tags: android, android-sdk

К примеру есть `SmsManager.getDefault()`, который устарел в API 31+, вместо него есть `Context.getSystemService(SmsManager.class)`.

Будет ли это работать на Android 5.0 или же функционал доступен от Android 9 и выше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [`SmsManager.getDefault()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager#getDefault()) появился в API 4 (Android 1.6) и помечен устаревшим в API 31 (Android 12). В документации написано, что вместо него лучше использовать [`Context.getSystemService(SmsManager.class)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getSystemService(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)), который доступен с API 23 (Android 6).

По-хорошему, если вы делаете приложение для Android 5 и выше, то вы можете использовать старый способ для Android 5 и новый способ для Android 6 и выше:

```kotlin
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    // новый способ для Android 6 и выше
    smsManager = context.getSystemService(SmsManager::class.java)
} else {
    // старый способ для Android 5
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault()
}
```

Вы можете проигнорировать новый способ и сделать все по-старому, но в какой-то момент в новых версиях Андроида старый способ перестанет работать, тогда вам все равно придется реализовывать функциональность по-новому.

Рекомендую подготовиться к изменениям заранее и реализовать функциональность двумя способами, чтобы не пришлось делать наспех в будущем, когда что-то внезапно перестанет работать.

Comment: А в чем разница между SmsManager и этим кодом: Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);

Comment: Задайте [новый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), чтобы его увидели другие участники сообщества. Я с SmsManager не сильно знаком, мой ответ про общую проблему использования старого и нового API (неважно какого именно).